# Proper syntax to define simple object factory via operator new

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, factory

Here is the basic outline of what I am trying to achieve

```
class Interface {
public:
  virtual ~Interface () {}
  virtual void work() = 0;
  static Interface *create();
  static void setFactory(std::function<Interface *()>);
}
```

in Interface.cpp I have

```
static std::function<Interface *()>  factory = nullptr;
Interface *Interface ::create() { return factory(); }
void Interface::setFactory(std::function<Interface *()> someFactory) {
   factory = someFactory;
}
```

separately I have

```
class Implementation : public Interface {
...
}
```

And I made sure to call

```
Interface::setFactory([]() -> Interface * { return new Implementation(); });
```

prior to making any calls to Interface::create(). What I am seeing is that static factory variable is set (no longer a nullptr), so the call to setFactory did work. However resulting factory is empty and calls to Interface::create() would crash. I could probably find a workaround by making a structure with operator() but I wonder if there is an error in my lambda expression.

It is probably worth mentioning that I am using MSVC2013

Comment: Based on the code you've posted I can see nothing that would cause the crash you describe. Can you create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Seems to be not your original implementation because class `Interface` has a dtor with a wrong name, so this should not compile. So maybe the problem lies in the code you haven't shown?

Answer (score 1):

You may have a static initialization order problem.

My theory is that your `factory` is assigned to *before* being constructed, then it is constructed (wiping its state), and then you call `create`.

MSVC2015 supports magic static local variables, which mostly solves that problem.

```
namespace {
  std::function<Interface *()>& factory() {
    static std::function<Interface *()> retval;
    return retval;
  }
}
```

now `factory()` wraps a static local variable that is guaranteed to be constructed at or before the first time you call the function, and only constructed once.

Doing something equivalent in MSVC2013 is harder.  If you know that there won't be multiple threads before `main` starts calling it, you can do the above plus:

```
static auto&& force_call = factory();
```

after it to force a call before `main` starts.

Comment: I already do something similar by having a static variable that is initialized by a call to a function which as a side effect constructs and sets the factory. I am about to finish MCVE (studio 2013 project) which I'd be happy to upload if I new where.

Comment: @dyp looks like you are right: I saw it in some CTPs for VS2013 and I guess I thought it made its way into an update.  I cannot find any evidence now, so is probably in error.

Comment: In the process of making MCVE I observed that the code continued crushing for as long as interface and implementation resided in different files. But when I moved everything into a single file together with main things magically started working. It does sound like the order of static initialization vs. construction should not be relied upon.

Comment: @Yakk AFAIK, you can use `run_once` in VS2013 as a workaround, which should only be slightly harder.

Comment: @LRaiz in each compilation unit, earlier "globals" are constructed first.  Between compilation units, there is no guaranteed order.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the insights and suggestions. I definitely learned something new. In the end I opted for a simple solution that is not specific to MSVC and does not depend on statics at all. However the solution is specific for my application because I have a point in my application where I know that everything is already running and thus I can set up my factory but before Interface class is ever instantiated.